# Moving to latest Macos broke my Xcode project... I can't include anything

Tags: c++, xcode

I've moved to latest OS & updated Xcode. But after that I can't compile my project. I have to prepend to all my includes with `"../"`. It's weird and problematic, as having to do that will break the project for Windows and Linux.

Is there a setting in Xcode or something to go back to the old way? This is bananas.

Comment: Reinstall xcode. How is your project configured? Please show a [mre]

Comment: It's a super overcomplicated photoshop plugin project which I have no idea how it works. I barely managed to duck tape it together. Since the last update all my imports needs ../ and that's all I know. Xcode changed something with paths and now I'm screwed :D Would posting Xcode project file help? Im more of a cmake&clion user, I only use xcode here because I have no other option till I learn how to redo it in cmake.